# Обеспечит ли двойная шифровка AES-256 стойкость к взлому в 2 раза выше?

Tags: криптография, aes

Хочу выяснить у людей разбирающихся в криптографии вот какой вопрос, ибо я не очень силён в таких делах.

Предположим у нас есть какие-то исходные данные размером 128 бит. Я их шифрую AES-256 с ключом key1, а затем, полученный шифр заново шифрую тем же AES-256, но для большей безопасности уже другим ключом key2.

Значит ли это что стойкость зашифрованной информации к взлом стала выше в 2 раза?

Comment: Насколько я себе представляю, стойкость увеличится даже больше чем в два раза. Приведу на этом примере https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B . При расшифровке расшифровщик ищет варианты, которые будут являться нормальным набором слов. А на самом деле ему надо искать вариант, который при ещё одной расшифровке превратится в нормальный набор слов. Получается что сложность не увеличивается в два раза, а возрастает в квадрат. Но я не уверен.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете не там. Почитайте для начала статью [_Вы опасно некомпетентны в криптографии_](http://habrahabr.ru/post/181372/), и поймите, что с наивным подходом («ключ вдвое длиннее — считать вдвое больше») можно сильно просчитаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сущности - да, атакующему придётся подбирать оба ключа, чтобы расшифровать исходное сообщение. Т.к. изначально это было 2^256, и ещё добавили 2^256, в результате стало 2^512. Только не понятно, зачем Вам это нужно. Ключ длиной в 256 бит прямым перебором не берётся, нет смысла его увеличивать.

Comment: А не будет ли это аналогично какому-то третьему ключу? Оригинал * Ключ1 * Ключ2 = Оригинал * Ключ3 ?

Comment: @KromStern, я не знаю, и гугл похоже тоже не знает. Видимо мало кто пока этим занимался или результатов нет. Если хочется погуглить самостоятельно, то стоит искать "functional composition group". Если AES формирует такую группу, тогда да, этот номер не пройдёт. Но на данный момент, похоже, не известно формирует AES группу или нет. Для DES [известно](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-48071-4_36#page-1). Но это стало известно через много лет после того, как DES стал стандартом. Видимо ещё не прошло достаточно времени для подобного исследования AES.

Answer (score 9):

Оба ключа отдельно перебирать не придётся, поскольку к двойному шифрованию можно применить атаку "[метод встречи посередине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5)".

Краткое описание такое. У нас есть два текста - незашифрованный (PT) и зашифрованный (CT). Начинаем подбирать ключи методом полного перебора. Каждым ключом шифруем незашифрованный текст (получаем PTX) и расшифровываем зашифрованный текст (получаем CTX). Результаты запоминаем. Пробуем следующий ключ и так далее. На каждой итерации проверяем, совпадает ли у нас получившийся PTX с одним из ранее запомненных CTX или получившийся CTX с одним из ранее запомненных PTX. Если совпадение найдено, мы нашли сразу оба ключа. Таким образом, для нахождения двух 256-битных ключей методом полного перебора нам потребуется максимум 2^257 операций шифрования/дешифрования, а вовсе не 2^512.